# $event in expression of angularjs template

Tags: angularjs

I am following angularJS documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

```
 <div ng-controller="EventController">
      <button ng-click="clickMe($event)">Event</button>
      <p><code>$event</code>: <pre> {{$event | json}}</pre></p>
      <p><code>clickEvent</code>: <pre>{{clickEvent | json}}</pre></p>
    </div>
```

**Note in the example above how we can pass in $event to clickMe, but how it does not show up in {{$event}}. This is because $event is outside the scope of that binding.**

Did not understand why $event is outside the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$event` is available ONLY FOR your `clickMe` function, nowhere else, so you must process it in that function, make a copy of it to be able access it outside of `clickMe` function scope.

Same for other event functions (ng-keypress, ng-keydown, ng-blur, etc...)

Example is showing it, `$event` outside of clickMe function is not defined after click on that button.